# Line breaks in booktabs?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx, booktabs

How do I fit such a table on a page (so that it's not too wide)? I guess I'd like to have a line break in the name of every column and also line breaks in each cell of the entire first column. How do I do that? (Or are there any other suggestions?)

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
        \toprule
        8 characters & 27 characters & 27 characters &  15 characters & 15 characters  \\
        \midrule
         longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 1  & 2  \\
         longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 3  & 4 \\
        longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 1  & 2  \\
         longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 3  & 4 \\
           \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{test}
    \label{test}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Maybe you can check out the X column type in package tabularx.

Comment: You might want to change the title of the question as booktabs only provides rules/lines for tables and thus have nothing to do with line breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `tabulary` to use `J`,`C`,`L` or `R` columns or combine these with standard columns types (`c`,`l`,`r`,`p`, ... run `textoc array` if you need to know about types of standard  columns)

The advantage over use `tabularx` is that set the alignment is just choosing between `J`,`C`,`L` or `R`and that, by default adjust the width of every column according to the amount of content, i.e., in two J columns, that with more text will be wider, while in two X column the width will be always the same (except doing some magic) no matter if one have much more text that the other. You can also fix a minimum and maximal width for this automatic adjustment to obtain better results (see the effect of `\tymax` in the example).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\tymax=300pt
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}JLCCC@{}}
      \toprule
      xxxxxxxx & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx & xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx & xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx  \\
      \midrule
      \lipsum[1][1-3] & yyy yyy yyyy  & zzzzzz & 1  & 2  \\\addlinespace
      \lipsum[1][4-6] & yyyy yyyyyy & zz zzzz & 3  & 4 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be an idea using `tabularx` but some details still need to be adjusted according to your specific document settings and the text in the table.

You need to set the width of  `P` column according to your requirement. (`P` is defined to be the centered `p`)
The `X` type will also fit the width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for better table control

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % centered p

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XP{2.5cm}P{2cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}}
      \toprule
      xxxxxxxx & xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx & xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx & xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx & xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx  \\
      \midrule
      \lipsum[1][1-3] & yyyyyyyyyy  & zzzzzz & 1  & 2  \\
      \lipsum[1][1-3] & yyyyyyyyyy & zzzzzz & 3  & 4 \\
      \lipsum[1][1-3] & yyyyyyyyyy & zzzzzz & 1  & 2  \\
      \lipsum[1][1-3] & yyyyyyyyyy & zzzzzz & 3  & 4 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{test}
    \label{test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a `tabularx` environment and employs the `X` column type, which allows automatic line breaking, in the first three columns. For now, the widths of the first three columns are the same. Please advise if you require a different approach.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}    % centered version of X column type
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}  % ragged-right version of X col. type
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L CC cc @{}}
\toprule
8 characters & 27 characters & 27 characters &  15 characters & 15 characters  \\
\midrule
longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 1  & 2  \\
longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 3  & 4 \\
longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 1  & 2  \\
longish text (150 characters) & short text (10 characters)  & short text (6 characters) & 3  & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{test} \label{tbl:test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```